# Как убрать поле выберите файл?

Tags: css, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать(спрятать) кнопку "Выберите файл"?

```
<div class="file-upload">
                         <label>
                              <input type="file" name="file">
                                  </label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `.file-upload label input { display: none; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.file-upload label input { display: none; }
```

или

```
.file-upload label input { opacity: 0; }
```

не забудьте обернуть в `<style>...</style>`, если не будете вставлять в css файл

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов спрятать элемент

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("deleted")[0];
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

```html
Как ничего не было
<div class="file-upload">
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="file" style="display:none;">
  </label>
</div>
<hr>
Возможно взаимодействовать но невидим и занимает место
<div class="file-upload">
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="file" style="opacity:0;">
  </label>
</div>
<hr>
Также возможно взаимодействовать но невидим и занимает место
<div class="file-upload">
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="file" style="visibility:hidden;">
  </label>
</div>
<hr>
Элемент удален, полезно если не нужно лишнее GET или POST поле
<div class="file-upload deleted">
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="file" style="visibility:hidden;">
  </label>
</div>
<hr>
Невозможно взаимодействовать но невидим и занимает место

<div class="file-upload">
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="file" style="visibility:hidden;" onclick="return false">
  </label>
</div>
<hr>
```